# How to throw error in dropzone for maxfilesize?

Tags: javascript, dropzone

In my code I set the filesize 1mb , its work fine  but doesnot throw any error message how can I set?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#my-dropzone").dropzone({
            maxFiles: 1,
            maxFilesize: 1,
            parallelUploads: 1,
            url: "upload.php",


            success: function (file,response) {


                file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");

            },

            error: function (file,response) {
                sv.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Just add the error message to a `div` or `console.log` in your error callback.

Answer (score 0):

As the dropzone documentation [says](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#events):

> Since listening to events can only be done on instances of Dropzone,
>   the best place to setup your event listeners, is in the init function

So set up the init callback and declare the `success` and `error` callbacks in the dropzone instance inside it:

```js
$("#my-dropzone").dropzone({
    maxFiles: 1,
    maxFilesize: 1,
    parallelUploads: 1,
    url: "upload.php",
    init: function() {  // first you need an init callback
        success: function(file, response) {
            alert("Yeehaw!");
        },
        error: function(file, response) {  // and then can you have your error callback
            alert("Bah humbug...");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider this equivalent example:

```
try {
    var foo = function() {
        throw new Error("foo error");
    }
}
catch (error) {
}

foo();
```

You wouldn't expect the error caused by calling foo to be caught just because at the time foo was defined execution was inside the try block.

One solution is of course to use try/catch inside the body of the function that might throw, as you have shown. Another solution is to create a reusable "catching wrapper" function, perhaps like this:

```
function catchIfException(func, handler) {
    return function() {
        try {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            func.apply(this, args);
        }
        catch (error) {
            handler(error);
        }
    };
}


    $(document).on('change', 'select', 
        catchIfException(
            function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();

                throw new Error('callPage method failed');
            }, 
            function(error) {
                console.log("error: " + error);
            }
        );
    );
```